# Need Help Changing Apache Server Name

Tags: apache

`Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch Server at owainstevens.sytes.net Port 80`

I need help in changing the server name any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: offtopic. not a programming questions. This is server configuration. Try the webmaster SE site.

Answer (score 0):

You should become familiar with the Apache documentation.  Hint:  [Apache Core Features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html).